# gstreamer pipeline for decklinksrc video capture card with udpsrc and udpsink using RTP

Tags: udp, ubuntu-12.04, video-capture, gstreamer, rtp

Hi and thank you for reading,

I'm having trouble figuring out what my gstreamer pipeline should look like to send my Blackmagic decklinksrc video from one Ubuntu machine to another on the same network using RTP and UDP.

To view the video locally I use this pipeline:
gst-launch-0.10 decklinksrc mode=11 connection=0 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink sync=false

This works perfectly fine on both machines with my local setups. Note that mode 11 is 1080i 59.94FPS.

Here is my rough pipeline for both the host machine and the client:

Client (started first):

```
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=6100 caps="application/x-rtp, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:2,width=(string)1920, height=(string)1080,colorimetry=(string)BT709-2, depth=(string)8" ! rtpvrawdepay ! xvimagesink
```

Host:

```
gst-launch-0.10 decklinksrc mode=11 connection=0 ! tee ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host=xx.xx.xxx.xx port=6100 tee0. ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

I've tried various parameters and I've tried multiple ports with no luck. Each time both machines output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ..
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

Any information to help explain the different attributes (e.g. rtpvrawpay) is appreciated. If you know what I'm doing wrong, even better!

Thanks,
Randy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it, 
Host :
gst-launch-0.10 decklinksrc mode=11 connection=0 ! videorate ! videoscale ! ffmpegcolorspace ! "video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)I420, width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)25/1" ! tee ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink host=192.168.40.103 port=6100 tee0. ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=false -v

client:
gst-launch-0.10 udpsrc port=6100 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW, sampling=(string)YCbCr-4:2:0, depth=(string)8, width=(string)1920, height=(string)1080" ! rtpvrawdepay ! xvimagesink

If doesn't work you can add -v option on each pipeline to know what is format using between each plugin.
I tried with videotestsrc on my computer and udp works. So with decklinksrc I am not sure this will works.